# Automatically change order status during specific hours and days in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to change the order status from processing to complete during normal business hours (8am-4pm, Monday-Friday).

I've got the following code which works but regularly stops working

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$is_week_days  = in_array( date('w'), array( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) ) ? true : false; // From Monday to Thursday
$is_friday     = date('w') == 5 ? true : false; // Friday
$is_week_end   = in_array( date('w'), array( 0, 6 ) ) ? true : false; // Weekend days

$start_time    = mktime('08', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 8am
$end_time      = mktime('16', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 4pm
$now_time      = time();

$after_tomorow = date('l', strtotime('+2 days'));

if (($is_week_days || $is_friday) && ($now_time >= $start_time && ($now_time < $end_time))) {
    $working_hours = 1;
} else {
    $working_hours = 0;
}

    if ($working_hours == 1  && $status != "completed") {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        return;
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

This is part of a bigger function that is triggered once an order is placed.

Is there an easier way of doing this via functions.php?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this code run now?  Is it part of a plugin?  What do you mean when you say it stops working?  Does it fail in some way, like there's a message in your log or something?  Or do you mean it stops being triggered for some reason?

Comment: If its wp cron job then its normal to stop if there are no visitors. Run your function with server cron job instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave S commented `Where does this code run now?` As I can see your code looks fine but it can improve a little better so I revised your code a little bit.

First, you added `$is_week_days` and `$is_friday` in the same condition so you can just add day `5` to `$is_week_days` to check for Friday as well.

You added extra round bracet in this condition `($now_time < $end_time)`

and, you can check this `$status != "completed"` case in your weekdays condition.

```
$is_week_days  = in_array( date('w'), array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) ) ? true : false; // From Monday to Friday
$start_time    = mktime( '08', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') ); // 8am
$end_time      = mktime( '16', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') ); // 4pm
$now_time      = time();

if ( $is_week_days && ( $now_time >= $start_time && $now_time <= $end_time ) && $status != "completed" ) {
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    return;
}
```